# How do I pass a ostream and use cout to display on the screen in a function?

Tags: c++

I want to use istream and ostream as a parameter that my functions take and help me to the work (read file, and display content on the screen).
I know how to do it with istream:

```
std::ifstream myfile(...);

void foo(myfile);

void readFoo(std::istream &stream)
{
  int x, y;
  stream >> x >> y;  //suppose my file contains many rows of 2 numbers.
  //store the x and y to somewhere 
}

void writeFoo(std::ostream &output)
{
???
}
```

And what object should I pass to my writeFoo()?

UPDATE:
Here is the update but I got an error message( cannot convert from ostream to ostream*)

```
writeFoo(std::cout);
writeFoo(sd::ostream &out)
{
  out << somedata to display to the screen;
}
```

Comment: If you want screen output, why take an arbitrary stream?

Comment: suppose I wanna stick with the ostream and istream?

Comment: If you want to use `cout` you don't need to pass an `ostream`. Just use `cout`.

Comment: No, that code does _not_ give that error actually: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b4758e79dda73dc86526cdb184169432-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass *any output stream* which derives from `std::ostream`.

For example:

```
writeFoo(std::cout);  //write to stdout

std::ofstream file("output.txt"); //open/create a file first
writeFoo(file);       //write to output.txt
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: THx! But I got a invalid conversion from ostream to ostream* error

Comment: @user1701840: then you're doing something else.

Comment: @user1701840: I cannot understand your update. Please read some introductory book on C++. You seem to not knowing the basics of C++.